# Emacs - org-mode insert checkbox

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I am starting to use `org-mode`, to organise... well everything.
I am following the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html).

Is there a binding in org-mode to insert items and checkboxes ?
Ie. something like this :

```
 * TODO Organize party [2/4]
   - [-] call people [1/3]
     - [ ] Peter
     - [X] Sarah
     - [ ] Sam
   - [X] order food
   - [ ] think about what music to play
   - [X] talk to the neighbors [CURSOR HERE]
```

And now if I do `M-x insert-checkbox-item` (or similar, I haven't found the command) :

```
 * TODO Organize party [2/4]
   - [-] call people [1/3]
     - [ ] Peter
     - [X] Sarah
     - [ ] Sam
   - [X] order food
   - [ ] think about what music to play
   - [X] talk to the neighbors
   - [ ] [CURSOR HERE]
```

*If possible*, it would respect the indentation too. This would mean keeping the new item at the level of indentation of the item where the cursor was when invoking the command. Which means that it may have to skip a few lines of lower-level items.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming point is already in a list like in your example, use `org-insert-todo-heading`, bound to `M-S-return` in Org by default. When point is in a checklist item `C-c C-c` will toggle its state.

This same binding will do other things depending on where point is, e.g. if you are at the end of a heading it will add another heading at the same level with a `TODO` keyword.

Answer (score 13):

Just `C-u` `C-c` `C-c` would do wherever your cursor on that line

Ref: https://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html

Answer (score 8):

1. For continuing checkbox lists (and ordinary lists) in `org-mode` I use  [org-autolist](https://github.com/calvinwyoung/org-autolist).

This should do exactly what you want.

2. Also, for creating a **new** checkbox item I defined an emacs [abbrev](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html) like so:

   `("rr" "- [ ]")`

This means that I can type "`rr` " and emacs inserts "`- [ ]` " which is great.